# how to export openlayer3 map to png with its scale bar using js

Tags: eclipse, openlayers-3

i am trying to export openlayer3 map to png using canvas in js. Actualy map div and scale bar div is different so while export map to png how to draw scale bar and its legends on same png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to create control and get control from html, then [add it to canvas](https://www.kreidefossilien.de/webgis/dokumentation/beispiele/export-map-to-png-with-scale) like this

```
InsertToCanvas = (function() {
 //get the canvas element
var canvas = $('canvas').get(0); 
//get the Scaleline div container the style-width property
var olscale = $('.ol-scale-line-inner');  
//Scaleline thicknes
var line1 = 6;
//Offset from the left
var x_offset = 10;
//offset from the bottom
var y_offset = 30;
var fontsize1 = 15;
var font1 = fontsize1 + 'px Arial';
// how big should the scale be (original css-width multiplied)
var multiplier = 2;

 /* go for it */
function WriteScaletoCanvas(e) {
var ctx = e.context;
var scalewidth = parseInt(olscale.css('width'),10)*multiplier;
var scale = olscale.text();
var scalenumber = parseInt(scale,10)*multiplier;
var scaleunit = scale.match(/[Aa-zZ]{1,}/g);

//Scale Text
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.font = font1;
ctx.strokeText([scalenumber + ' ' + scaleunit], x_offset + fontsize1 / 2, canvas.height - y_offset - fontsize1 / 2);
ctx.fillText([scalenumber + ' ' + scaleunit], x_offset + fontsize1 / 2,     canvas.height - y_offset - fontsize1 / 2);

//Scale Dimensions
var xzero = scalewidth + x_offset;
var yzero = canvas.height - y_offset;
var xfirst = x_offset + scalewidth * 1 / 4;
var xsecond = xfirst + scalewidth * 1 / 4;
var xthird = xsecond + scalewidth * 1 / 4;
var xfourth = xthird + scalewidth * 1 / 4;

// Stroke
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = line1 + 2;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
ctx.moveTo(x_offset, yzero);
ctx.lineTo(xzero + 1, yzero);
ctx.stroke();

//sections black/white
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = line1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
ctx.moveTo(x_offset, yzero);
ctx.lineTo(xfirst, yzero);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = line1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFFFFF";
ctx.moveTo(xfirst, yzero);
ctx.lineTo(xsecond, yzero);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = line1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
ctx.moveTo(xsecond, yzero);
ctx.lineTo(xthird, yzero);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = line1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFFFFF";
ctx.moveTo(xthird, yzero);
ctx.lineTo(xfourth, yzero);
ctx.stroke();
}
function postcompose() {
map.on('postcompose', function (evt) {
    WriteScaletoCanvas(evt);
});
}

return {
postcompose : postcompose
};
})();

InsertToCanvas.postcompose();

//Now export map as png

   var exportMap = function () {


          canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
          canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
              alert("jsp page export map function"); 
            saveAs(blob, 'map.png');
          })
        }
```

This way scale bar will be added to png.

Step 2 For legend

```
  function WriteLegendtoCanvas(e) {  
    var ctx = e.context;


    var x=50,y=50;
    var arr = $('div#legendId img');

    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {

      var img = new Image();
    img.src = $(arr[i]).attr('src');
    img.onload = function() { ctx.drawImage(img, x, y); }
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y); 
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = line1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    y+=20;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();

    }

        }
```

And call this function with postcompose

```
    function postcompose() {
            map.on('postcompose', function (evt) {
                WriteScaletoCanvas(evt);
                WriteLegendtoCanvas(evt);
            });
        }
```